# What's the difference between these Windows API signatures in Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

Looking Windows.pas in Delphi, I see that there are several signatures as `LoadLibrary (A) or (W)` for loading a specific module. What are the differences between them and could I trust to call LoadLibrary always for all types of Windows platforms?

Comment: In short ...
There is a call of difference between these two LoadLibrary and LoadLibraryW signatures in Delphi?

Comment: I can understand the downvotes, but I don't understand how it's unclear what's being asked. Updated the title to reflect the question being asked.

Comment: @JerryDodge The edit makes a much better question.  I have voted to re-open this question.  If you also feel your edit has sufficiently improved the question then you are free to do the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Windows API provides either ANSI strings (`A`) or Unicode strings (`W`). Interally, the Windows API has both available. However, Delphi is defaulted to either one or the other, depending on the version of Delphi. Many other Windows languages do this too. The language uses either ANSI or Unicode strings as a default.

In Delphi versions prior to 2009, the ANSI API calls were used, suffixed with an `A`. That was when Delphi primarily used ANSI strings. As of Delphi 2009 and above, Unicode has been enforced. That also made the default API calls to Unicode, suffixed with a `W`. Unicode has always been supported in Delphi, but as of 2009 it's been enforced as the default, favored over ANSI. In those older versions, functions such as `LoadLibrary` mapped to the ANSI version `LoadLibraryA`.

The particular API call you're referring to `LoadLibrary` is available as either `LoadLibraryA` or `LoadLibraryW`. `Windows.h` also provides a generic `LoadLibrary` function, which internally uses the preferred Unicode version. The `A` and `W` difference provides developers the option for backwards compatibility, as with many of Microsoft's products. If the language is primarily ANSI Strings, you can explicitly use Unicode. Or, if the language is primarily Unicode, you can explicitly use ANSI.

Long story short, at one point Windows itself made the switch from ANSI strings to Unicode strings as default. However still provided backwards compatibility. Later Delphi versions have been changed to use whatever the preferred defaults are - in this case they're Unicode.

To summarize:

- LoadLibraryA - Loads library via ANSI strings
- LoadLibraryW - Loads library via Unicode strings
- LoadLibrary - Loads library using preferred default (Unicode Strings)
- Ancient versions of Windows used only ANSI strings before introducing Unicode
- Windows provided backwards compatibility by defaulting to ANSI versions - but eventually switched defaults to Unicode (not sure at which version)

You can learn more about [Microsoft's introduction of Unicode here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page) as well as [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374089(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Looking Windows.pas see desnesserario LoadLibrary be a "redundant" signature let's call it ...
Another would doubt if there is a preference of those calls according to Windows x86 and x64 platform?

Comment: 32bit and 64bit typically consist of entirely different copies of the same library compiled for either platform - working in the exact same manner as each other. However that's an entirely different story.

Comment: Your third paragraph is a little shaky. There is no `LoadLibrary` function in *kernel32.dll*. The function with that name exists only in *Windows.pas*, where it's simply another function import, mapped either to `LoadLibraryA` or `LoadLibraryW`, depending on Delphi version. Windows NT–8 implements the A version by converting to Unicode and calling the W version. Windows 95–ME didn't have a W version, except via MSLU, which converted the input to ANSI and called the A version.

Comment: @Rob Honestly, I felt my entire answer was shaky :-/ But when looking into `Winapi.Windows` in Delphi XE8, I don't see such a mapping (as I was actually expecting) - it's direct... And when looking at the WinAPI documentation, it explains a generic version is available: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374089(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It's "available" through a macro in *windows.h*, not anything present in the OS. Put `#define UNICODE ` in your C program and the generic functions will be the W functions. Otherwise, they'll be the A functions. Delphi doesn't support that kind of conditional compilation, so the mapping is set based on Delphi version. Check some other units if you can't find generic `LoadLibrary` in *Windows.pas*.

Comment: @Rob I see, I'm used to just referencing what the Pascal tells me in `Winapi.Windows`. So it all has to do with how Delphi imports the Windows API behind the scenes.

Comment: FWIW, There is a performance overhead calling A versions of windows API, since it implicit converts AnsiString to Unicode and then call the W versions of it.

Comment: @RobKennedy well, Delphi DOES support conditional compilation, it is just that apart from C++ it compiles other modules like RTL separately and before than compiling main EXE, so conditional compilation phase of Windows API declarations already happened before you start compiling your main project

Comment: Right, @Arioch. I chose my words carefully: It doesn't support *that kind* of conditional compilation. In particular, the kind that would be relevant to the discussion at hand.

Comment: @Rob 'kay, then I expanded your word what it means "that kind"
///
Though personally in my book it is not that "that kind" is not supported but merely that with default search paths "that kind" is not called for.
But there is no real problem to trigger Delphi into recompiling RTL together with your monolithic apps - it is just not trendy.
/// I think the correct way would be to say that it is C++ which does not support "this way" (modularized) of compilation, and modern tools like Delphi and C# do support modern ways, thus they cannot rely on CC which only works in legacy C++ compilation mode.

Answer (score 7):

> why there is in Delphi XE2 LoadLibrary and LoadLibraryW when they are the same api in Windows?

For compatibility with the Win32 API and various tutorials/examples, and for compatibility with Ansi and Unicode versions of Delphi.

The Win32 API defines only `LoadLibraryA()` (Ansi) and `LoadLibraryW()` (Unicode) as actual functions (exported from kernel32.dll).  `LoadLibrary()` is not a function at all, it is a **preprocessor macro** (defined in `winbase.h`) that maps to either `LoadLibraryA()` or `LoadLibraryW()`, based on whether the project is configured to compile for an Ansi or Unicode environment:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define LoadLibrary  LoadLibraryW
#else
#define LoadLibrary  LoadLibraryA
#endif
```

When a C/C++ app uses a `TCHAR`-based string to call the generic `LoadLibrary()` "function", it can be compiled and linked for either environment by simply changing the project settings rather than changing the source code, eg:

```
HMODULE hLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("filename"));
// calls either LoadLibraryA("filename") or LoadLibraryW(L"filename")
// depending on whether UNICODE is defined while compiling...
```

Delphi, on the other hand, does not support `.h` files, and thus cannot utilize all of Microsoft's existing function declarations.  All library functions and data types have to be re-declared in Pascal (hence the existence of the `Windows` unit and other related units for the Win32 API).

In the case of `LoadLibrary()`, all versions of Delphi declare `LoadLibraryA()` and `LoadLibraryW()` as real functions imported from `kernel32.dll`, using `PAnsiChar` and `PWideChar` parameters, respectively:

```
function LoadLibraryA(const lpFileName: PAnsiChar): HMODULE; stdcall; external kernel32 name 'LoadLibraryA';
function LoadLibraryW(const lpFileName: PWideChar): HMODULE; stdcall; external kernel32 name 'LoadLibraryW';
```

Delphi does not support preprocessor macros, so it declares `LoadLibrary()` as a function that imports whichever DLL function matches Delphi's generic `PChar` type.  So, in Delphi 2007 and earlier where `PChar` is `PAnsiChar`, `LoadLibrary()` is declared to import `LoadLibraryA()`, and in Delphi 2009 and later where `PChar` is `PWideChar`, `LoadLibrary()` is declared to import `LoadLibraryW()` instead:

```
// Delphi 2007 and earlier...
function LoadLibrary(const lpFileName: PChar): HMODULE; stdcall; external kernel32 name 'LoadLibraryA';
```

```
// Delphi 2009 and later...
function LoadLibrary(const lpFileName: PChar): HMODULE; stdcall; external kernel32 name 'LoadLibraryW';
```

When a Delphi app uses a `PChar` to call the generic `LoadLibrary()`, it can be compiled in multiple versions of Delphi without having to change source code:

```
hLib := LoadLibrary(PChar(filename));
// calls either LoadLibraryA(PAnsiChar(filename) or LoadLibraryW(PWideChar(filename))
// depending on whether Delphi natively uses Ansi or Unicode strings...
```

These factors apply to **any** `TCHAR`-based API, not just to `LoadLibrary()` specifically.  When a given Win32 API supports `A` and `W` versions, MSDN documents it in terms of its generic `TCHAR` version.  Remember that the Win32 API predates Unicode, and `TCHAR` was Microsoft's solution to migrate developers from Ansi APIs to Unicode APIs when they were first introduced in Windows NT, while still allowing developers to support earlier Windows versions.  For backwards compatibility with legacy apps, those existing Ansi APIs are still supported in modern Windows versions, albeit deprecated in favor of the Unicode APIs.  New APIs introduced tend to be Unicode-only moving forward.

Comment: Technically `TCHAR` is part of the C++ runtime rather than Win32

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Actually, it is not part of C++ at all.  You might be thinking of `_TCHAR` in the C runtime library.  `TCHAR` is the Win32 equivilent.

Comment: Clearly it's not part of either C++ or C which are standardised languages/libraries and could not define a type that only has meaning on Windows. I certainly never said that TCHAR was part of C++. It is part of a library which is what I said. I should have said "MS C++ runtime". `TCHAR` is defined by the MSVC runtime library in the `tchar.h` header. But then MS confuse the matter by defining it again in `winnt.h`. Ho hum. What I think of as `TCHAR` is the MSVC library. I should have said nothing at all. Sorry.