# What does the letter A stand for at the end of identifiers of some windows.h functions?

Tags: c++, windows

Look at the names of some functions defined in the `windows.h` header files:

- [LoadLibraryA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya)
- [CreateProcessA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa)
- [BeginUpdateResourceA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-beginupdateresourcea)

They all end with the capital letter A. What does it stand for?

Also some of the functions like these:

- [BeginUpdateResourceW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-beginupdateresourcew)
- [BackupEventLogW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-backupeventlogw)

These end with the letter W. What does that stand for?

Comment: hi interesting, this might be of interest not sure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699776/whats-the-difference-between-these-windows-api-signatures-in-delphi

Comment: It stands for ANSI

Comment: "ASCII" vs. "Wide Characters"?

Comment: @IronMan Yeah, now I get it. The linked question was not easy to find in preemptive search. Thank you.

Comment: There are Unicode and ANSI versions of WinAPi functions. This MSDN [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/unicode-in-the-windows-api) describes the details.